# Check if a string is palindrome ignoring whitespace and special characters

Tags: python, palindrome

So, basically I want to check if a string is palindrome or not

I know I can simply use

```
def palindrome(n):
    return n == n[::-1]
```

It works fine, but if I want a string, for example "A cat, one crab, lol: barcenotaca."
to be true as well, what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
def palindrome(n):
    n = n.lower()
    n = ''.join(char for char in n if char.isalpha())
    return n==n[::-1]
```

Checking for `char.isalpha()` lets you ignore everything that's not a letter (when combined with the `n = n.lower()`, it basically checks for only lowercase letters) That way, you ignore all the punctuation and whitespace

Comment: what if I want to use stack and a queue to test the parameter string?

Comment: @user3672933: what have you tried, and why doesn't it work? I've provided a very pythonic answer, so if you're looking for something different, please show us how/why

Answer (score 2):

```
def palindrome(n):
    x = ''.join([x.lower() for x in n if x.isalpha()])
    return x == x[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

try checking if every letter in the given string is in the alphabet first, goes something like this

```
import string
def palindrome(str):
    alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase
    temp=""
    for c in str.lower():
        if c in alphabet:
            temp+=c
    return temp==temp[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def palindrome():
    stringOne = alphaCheck("give me a lovely palindrome")
    stringTwo = stringOne[::-1]
    for i in stringOne:
        print(i)
    for j in stringTwo:
        print(j)
    if stringOne == stringTwo:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def alphaCheck(prompt):
    stringOne = input(prompt)
    stringOne = stringOne.replace(" ", "")
    stringOne = stringOne.lower()
    while not stringOne.isalpha():
        stringOne = input(prompt)
    return stringOne

print(palindrome())
```

this method allows you to input your own palindrome and also checks to ensure that it only contains alphabetic characters. if you want to change that to only digits change while not stringOne.isalpha( ) to is